# Why it is a good practice to right try catch in foreach loop?

Tags: c#

Why is this code not working? Where as when I put the try catch in the foreach, it works fine. I need to know the reason. Please help.

```
try
{
    mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
    mySqlConnection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionstring"].ToString();

    mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("spSocialGetUniqueWords", mySqlConnection);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in url)
    {
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter("@uniqueKeyWords", pair.Key));

        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter("@counts", pair.Value));

        mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        mySqlCommand.Connection.Open();
        count = mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mySqlCommand.Connection.Close();          
    }                
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                
}
```

Comment: Define "not working"?

Comment: NEVER DO TRY CATCH WITHOUT HANDLING THE EXCEPTION
NEVER
NEVER
NEVER

write the exception to log. and check whats wrong

Comment: I suppose you have exception. Put breakpoint in *catch* block. Or even better - handle that exception (log, show to user, etc)

Comment: Error - Procedure or function spSocialGetUniqueWords has too many arguments specified.

Comment: I am handling the error...
 catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TraceService("Error at populateData " + DateTime.Now + "----" + ex.Message);
            }

Comment: Try to check if procedure spSocialGetUniqueWords() declares both  {uniqueKeyWords} and {counts} parameters on the data source you are connecting to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not working, it is running once, then it is failling but you are catching `Exception` but not doing anything with it. The problem with your code is that you are adding duplicate parameters. You should clear them after each loop:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in url)
{
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();

    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter("@uniqueKeyWords", pair.Key));

    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter("@counts", pair.Value));

    mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    mySqlCommand.Connection.Open();
    count = mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    mySqlCommand.Connection.Close();          
}
```

Comment: Or better, define the parameters before entering the loop. Inside the loop change only their values (no need to clear and rebuild the parameter collection)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are encountering an error on the first iteration of the loop.

Because your try/catch block is outside the loop, the entire loop stops executing, whereas if you put it inside the loop, if the first iteration contains an error and the second doesn't, the code can still try and execute the second iteration.

This code may potentially work better though, assuming the error is that you aren't clearing the parameters:

```
using (mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
{
    mySqlConnection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionstring"].ToString();

    using (mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("spSocialGetUniqueWords", mySqlConnection))
    {
        mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        mySqlConnection.Open();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in url)
        {
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();

            mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter("@uniqueKeyWords", pair.Key));

            mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter("@counts", pair.Value));

            count = mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  
        }
    }
}
```

I have refactored your code to use using blocks, which eliminates the need to call `Close` on the connection object and will also properly dispose of it when code execution exits the using block.

I have also cleared the parameters collection before adding new ones, moved some property setters nearer to the instantiation of the object (as they don't rely on anything else) and moved the `SqlConnection.Open()` call outside of the foreach loop as this will save on resources and execution time. It will also help towards not swamping the SQL Server with connections, which can quite severely affect performance.